# Windows 10 and filenames starting with "cookies"

Tags: security, windows-10

I had issues cloning a git repo and it turned out that my copy of Windows 10 has issues with filenames that begin with `cookies`.

To check whether this is just a local issue can somebody with Windows 10 check this by doing the following:

1. Use `cmd` to open the command prompt.
2. `cd` to your Desktop.
3. `echo . > cookies`
4. Try to open the file in either VSCode or Wordpad.

For me VSCode reports `Unable to open 'cookies': Unable to read file` and Wordpad reports `Access to \path\cookies was denied.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this was some kind of unidentified rootkit that was locking all files that had names starting with `cookies`... it is too much of a coincidence that this was only happening with files that could allow an attacker to clone my browser sessions (so they would be logged in as me on all the sites I am).

Incidentally, it worked fine in safe mode but no virus scanners (running inside and outside the OS) could see it.

Ultimately I decided to reinstall the OS to fix the issue.